# Multiple linux commands not returning expected results

Tags: php, ubuntu, command-line, command

I'm converting a web application from a Windows environment to Linux (Ubuntu). I have a page, served under lighttpd and PHP5, and I'm getting odd resultsPHP is not running in safe mode and I don't have any disabled_functions defined.

I'm trying to imitate the following terminal command:

> /usr/local/bin/findscu -S -k "0008,0052=STUDY" -k "0020,000d" 192.168.56.1 5678

This results in a stream of information back, resulting in 8 lines of information, when run from the terminal. There are spaces between each parameter (just wanted to ensure that that's noted here).

My PHP file contains the following

```
$cmd = '/usr/local/bin/findscu';
$param = ' -S -k "0008,0052=STUDY" -k "0020,000d" 192.168.56.1 5678';
$param = ''; // $retVal = 0, $output=63 elements
$fullcmd = $cmd.$param;
$perms = fileperms($cmd);
$info = exec($fullcmd,$output,$retVar);
echo $fullcmd;
echo '<p>Permissions : '.substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($cmd)), -4);
echo '<p>I am running as '.exec('whoami');
echo '<p>Return value : '.$retVar;

echo '<br>No of elements : '.count($output);
if(count($output)>1){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($output);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
```

As you'll see, I'm defining $param twice, on line 2 and then again on line 3, effectively over-writing $param as blank.  When I run this, I get the same results as I would on the terminal, basically the "man" page for findscu, containing 64 lines of output (63 elements of the returning array)

```
/usr/local/bin/findscu
Permissions : 0755
I am running as www-data
Return value : 0
No of elements : 63

Array
(
    [0] => $dcmtk: findscu v3.6.0 2011-01-06 $
    [1] => 
    [2] => findscu: DICOM query (C-FIND) SCU
    [3] => usage: findscu [options] peer port [dcmfile-in...]
```

... and so forth

However, when I comment line 3 out, therefore defining my $param variable as I would expect, I get a $retVar=0 (which is good, the command ran with no errors) but the count of the returning array also contains 0 elements.

This is the resulting page content:

```
/usr/local/bin/findscu -S -k '0008,0052=STUDY' -k '0020,000d' 192.168.56.1 5678
Permissions : 0755
I am running as www-data
Return value : 0
No of elements : 0
```

I can't see what on earth I'm doing wrong here.  I'm **sure** it's got something to do with spaces but I can't see it.  I've tried setting up $param with double quotes, single quotes, backslashes before each of them individually and even tried $cmd='the whole command in one variable'.

It's getting late and I'm sure I'm too tired to see it, but I need some help here!!

Any thoughts?

(BTW, this is the output from terminal:)

```
root@ubuntu:/home/pry/OSID# /usr/local/bin/findscu -S -k '0008,0052=STUDY' -k '0020,000d' 192.168.56.1 5678
W: ---------------------------
W: Find Response: 1 (Pending)
W: 
W: # Dicom-Data-Set
W: # Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Implicit
W: (0008,0052) CS [STUDY ]                                 #   6, 1 QueryRetrieveLevel
W: (0020,000d) UI [1.3.46.670589.5.2.10.2156913941.892665384.993397] #  48, 1    StudyInstanceUID
W:
```

Comment: Oh - and I've checked with Apache2 and the same thing happens, so now I know it's not a LIGHTTPD issue.

Comment: Now - interestingly, I see that the response that I should be getting assigned to my array ($output) is being logged in the apache2 error.log?

Answer (score 0):

and now I know ... appending 2>&1 to the end of the command redirects the output back to standard **output** as opposed to standard **error**. Interestingly I suppose it's semantics as to whether my command output is in fact an *error* as opposed to the **expected** response!?